# pushview different type of controllers getting different result

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I created a TabBarController with 5 navControllers (rootviewcontroller: 5 UICollectionViewControllers).
When I try to create new controllers under 1 of these 5 UICollectionViewControllers, I found the issue below:

When I pushview to `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, I just simply type, for example:

```
let editProfileController = EditProfileController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(editProfileController, animated: true)
```

However, when I try to pushview to `UICollectionViewController`, and I use the same line above, I got an `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error pointing `AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`. error output is 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Could anyone tell me why? and how I can solve the issue? I don't use storyboard.

Comment: I guess there is an error in console debug when it crashes? Could you share it with us?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: No more info just the lines before that message?

Comment: no more info I just edited the question, so you can have more detail about my project.

Comment: When I tried to debug the error, I duplicated two copies, one copy pushview to TableViewController or UIViewController, one copy pushview to uicollectionViewController. The formal one had no issue. The latter one crashed

Comment: I think problem in your UICollectionViewController. Did you use storyboard before and then delete? show us your UICollectionViewController code

Comment: No I code programmatically from the very beginning

Answer (score 0):

After doing research, I have found the answer:

If the controller I am going to go is UICollectionViewController I have to specify the following:

```
    let activityController = ActivityController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(activityController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You didn't had an error in console saying: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'`?. That's the error I was asking about in console.